# when deploying mvc 2 to a server, is it just the .dll that are changed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

when deploying to mvc 2 rc to a server, all we need to do is deploy the updated .dll's for mvc correct?

i.e. nothing has to be installed on the server?

BTW, After installing MVC RC, where are the new .dll's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, look in the references section of your project. Right-click the reference and select Properties. Under Properties, change Copy Local to True. It will be copied to the build directory when you re-build your project and copied to the target server when you publish.

My MVC 2 DLLs are located here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 2\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct.